# wordpress permalinks not working 500 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, posts

i made a mess of some kind my website was running perfectly but i did some changes to wpconfig i cant seem to remember and the result is that if i dont use permalinks and use simple page id the whole website works and if i try to use permalinks all the individual links break but home page as well as admin panel keeps working .

It always gives 500 internal server error

Any one got any ideas what could have gone wrong .

P.S.> I have deleted .htaccess and created a new one and copied the code given by wordpress but its still not working.

my website is [NewsKase](http://newskase.com)

Comment: And a new wp-config copy .but U need to add ur database username and password there .or go to wp-admin/update-core.php and then click reinstall WordPress . I think that will help you without any loss

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. My WordPress site was running perfectly until I changed my permalinks. All my individual links break but the main page as well as admin panel keeps working. When I use simple page id as permalink the whole website works.

The are several thing that can cause this problem. The following post lists some possibilities you can go through to find the root of your permalink problem.

https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/07/29/self-hosted-wordpress-permalink-problems/

Comment: Don't post link only answers. Links can disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Get a fresh copy of wp-config.php and enter in your DB details
   (username, pw, name, table prefix).
2. Delete htaccess file
3. Regenerate permalinks (admin - settings - permalinks)
4. Ensure server has mod-rewrite on